# Direct encode/decode does not result in original data

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I want to create a RSA key pair and use it for encoding/decoding data. My code is quite short but I cannot find any error.

Can anyone help me finding my problem?

Thanks for every hint!

```
// Generate key pair.
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

// Data to encode/decode.
byte[] original = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.".getBytes("UTF8");

// Encode data with public key.
Cipher cipherEncoder = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
cipherEncoder.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] encodedData = cipherEncoder.doFinal(original);

// Decode data with private key.
Cipher cipherDecoder = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
cipherDecoder.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] decodedData = cipherEncoder.doFinal(encodedData);

// Output.
System.out.println(new String("Original data:   " + new String(original, "UTF8")));
System.out.println(new String("Encoded/decoded: " + new String(decodedData, "UTF8")));
```

The output at the end seems to be quirky.

Comment: Textbook RSA (without padding) is really insecure. PKCS#1 v1.5 padding (11 bytes overhead) also shouldn't be used. Nowadays, OAEP is recommended (42 bytes overhead for SHA1).

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for this hint! Do you have an OAEP code example for me?

Comment: What do you mean? Just change the padding in the Cipher string and there you go. You don't need to change anything else. The available padding strings can be found in the Cipher class documentation.

Comment: Okay. On most websites I find examples with use of BouncyCastle. But when I understand you right, I do not need it? Sorry for my newbee questions!

Comment: Everything found. Thanks a lot!
[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are using the `cipherEncoder` to decode your data. You probably meant to use `cipherDecoder`. Secondly, you are going to have issues using RSA without padding (namely, your data will have a load of `0` bytes at the start). I would recommend you at least use PKCS1 padding. Here is the code after those changes.

```
// Generate key pair.
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.genKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

// Data to encode/decode.
byte[] original = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.".getBytes("UTF8");

// Encode data with public key.
Cipher cipherEncoder = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipherEncoder.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] encodedData = cipherEncoder.doFinal(original);

// Decode data with private key.
Cipher cipherDecoder = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipherDecoder.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] decodedData = cipherDecoder.doFinal(encodedData);

// Output.
System.out.println(new String("Original data:   " + new String(original, "UTF8")));
System.out.println(new String("Encoded/decoded: " + new String(decodedData, "UTF8")));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and finding my error. Great work!